# How to set id for widgets in kivy from python code file

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

```
class NavigationDrawer(MDApp):
def build(self):
    return Builder.load_string(KV)

def on_start(self):

    files=[{"price":"890" , "meter" : "36" , "elevator" : "True"}]

    for file in files:
        first_base_el = MDCard(size_hint=(1, None), size=(self.root.width,
              self.root.height / 4))
        second_base_el =BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')

        for element in file.keys() :

            external_el = MDRectangleFlatButton(
                    text=f'{element} : {file[element]}',
                    size_hint=(1, .2)
            )

            second_base_el.add_widget(external_el)

        first_base_el.add_widget(second_base_el)
        self.root.ids.container.add_widget(first_base_el)
```

> I get this error :     self.ids[element] = weakref.ref(external_el)
> AttributeError: 'NavigationDrawer' object has no attribute 'ids'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "id" assigned from python code does not work as an "id" from kivy lang, the best way to refer a widget added from python code, is using the "children" or "parent" attribute and getting the right widget from the widget tree, and using it by call or by object

In your example, the "first_base_el" has the widgets you have added, so to get the widget you've already added you should use:

B=first_base_el.children

Card=B[0] #this equals to "second_base_el" widget

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is because right not in the line  `self.root.ids.container.add_widget(first_base_el)` , self is referring to the AppClass and you are then accessing the root of the appclass which is itself.

The AppClass doesn't have any attribute `ids`. Only widget classes will have the ids attribute to access